# Motzkin polynomials and enumeration of chord diagrams

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, differential-equations, discrete-geometry, sequences-and-series

On page 12 of the paper [Enumeration of chord diagrams on many intervals and their non-orientable analogs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0967)" by Alexeev, Andersen, Penner, and Zograf is a list of polynomials which are a refinement of the first few Motzkin polynomials listed in OEIS [A055151](https://oeis.org/A055151).

Can anyone provide a proof that this relation between the two sets of polynomials holds for all higher degrees in general?

Edit 3/30/2023:

A further refinement of the array on p. 12 of Alexeev et al., reading along the diagonal, is A350499, the coefficients of the inverse noncrossing partitions / inverse refined Narayana polynomials / inverse parking functions (etc.) $[N^{(-1)}]$.

For example, starting with the first summand of $k = 2$ and plucking off the diagonal summands gives

$qs^2 + 3qs + 2$.

Compare this with

$m_3 - 3m_2m_2 + 2 m_1^2 = N^{(-1)}_n$.

Another example, starting with $k =4$, the diagonal is

$qs^4 + (5q + 5q^2) + (15 q + 15 q^2) + 35qs + 14$

compared with

$m_5 - 5 m_2  m_3 - 5  m_4 m_1 + 15  m_2^2 m_1 + 15 m_3 m_1^2 - 35 m_2 m_1^3 + 14 m_1^5 =  N^{(-1)}_5.$

Finally, the initial numbers for the next diagonal

$(1, 6, 9,21, 42, 7, 56, 84, ?, Catalan \; 42?)$

are a coarsening of the coefficients of $N^{(-1)}_6$,

$(1, 6, (6, 3), 21, 42, 7, 56, 84, 126, 42).$

The array in the paper is derived from random matrix integration methods, which seem inevitably to arrive at some basic equations of free probability exemplified by eqns. 33-36.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bijection between planar partial chord diagrams and Motzkin paths is the following: the left end of a chord corresponds to U-step, the right end of a chord corresponds to D step, and "free" marked point corresponds to H step. For  example, the last diagram on Figure 3 in the paper is encoded by a UUHHDDUHHD Motzkin path. 
It is well-known, that the number of 2n-gon gluings into a sphere is n^th Catalan number, and so there is a bijection between planar polygon gluings and Dyck paths.
This is basically the same relation you mentioned.

Comment: Do you mind if I cite this answer in the OEIS? Btw, the coefficients of these polynomials factor to give relations to other entries of the OEIS that have been  in the queue for publishing for a couple of days now.

Comment: Sure! I don't mind. Could you give me a link of these new entries?

Comment: Good. I don't think you can access the draft edits unless you are a registered contributor to the OEIS. I'll send you pfds through e-mail of the current drafts.